# Remote Desktop/Terminal Services API for Windows 8 Metro

Tags: api, microsoft-metro, remote-desktop, rdp, terminal-services

I am having a rather difficult time finding an API to tap into RDP in Visual Studios 2012 for metro style apps, is this available?

Comment: Is there an API for non-metro apps?

Comment: @Gabe: Here is some documentation for non-metro apps - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383464(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Here are some documentation regarding remote desktop for metro style apps -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh994983.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh994406.aspx

Comment: This is Javascript based, is there not a control option available as there was for non-metro style apps?